# Linear $f\colon \mathbb{F}^t \to \mathbb{F}^s$ injective on any ball of radius $\epsilon t$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, coding-theory

This may be well-known or trivial, but I cannot find any relevant pointer on the subject. Let $t\geq 1$ be an integer, and fix $\epsilon\in(0,1)$. I would like to find an integer $s=s(t,\epsilon)$ and a matrix $M\in\mathbb{F}_2^{s\times t}$ such that the (linear) transformation
$$
f\colon x\in \mathbb{F}_2^t \mapsto Mx \in \mathbb{F}_2^s
$$
is injective on each Hamming ball of radius $\epsilon t$; that is, if $x\neq y \in\mathbb{F}_2^t$ and $x,y$ differ on at most $\epsilon t$ coordinates, then $Mx\neq My$. The goal is to achieve this with $s$ being as small as possible.

Clearly, denoting by $V_{t,\ \epsilon}$ the volume of a Hamming ball of radius $\epsilon t$ in $\mathbb{F}_2^t$, one must have $$s\geq \log_2 V_{t,\ \epsilon} = h_2(\epsilon)t+o(t)$$ where $h_2$ is the binary entropy function. Is this lower bound tight (and if so, which $M$ would achieve it)?

Has anybody encountered this question (or a similar one) somewhere?

Thank you,

-- Clément.

Comment: Look for "Hamming bound", "Gilbert-Varshamov bound" and "sphere-packing bound" in a coding theory textbook for _lots_ of information about this topic.

Comment: I had the impression that these bounds address a different problem, though: I don't look for a mapping such that each $y\in\mathbb{F}_2^s$ is *covered* by some $f(x)$; I want $f$ to keep close messages apart (but does not have to keep far-away messages distinct).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a $[N, K]$ linear code $\mathcal C$ over $\mathbb F_2$.  Write the
codewords as row vectors, and let $H$ denote the paritycheck matrix of the code.
Then, $H$ is a $(N-K)\times N$ matrix and we have that
$${\mathbf c} \in \mathcal C ~\text{if and only if}~~  \mathbf cH^T = \mathbf 0$$
where $\mathbf 0$ is the zero vector in $\mathbb F_2^{N-K}$.  Note that $H$ is a linear
map from $\mathbb F_2^N$ to $\mathbb F_2^{N-K}$.

For a given nonzero $\mathbf z \in \mathbb F_2^{N-K}$, the set of vectors 
$\mathbf x \in \mathbb F_2^N$ such that $\mathbb x H^T = \mathbb z$ is called
a *coset* of the code. It is, of course, a translate of $\mathcal C$, and if
the minimum Hamming distance of $\mathcal C$ is $D$, then any two vectors
in the coset also are at Hamming distance $D$ or more from each other.

Turning to the OP's problem, if $\mathbf x, \mathbf y \in \mathbb F_2^N$
are at *distance smaller than $D$ from each other,* then they necessarily
must belong to two different cosets of the code, and so it must be that
$\mathbf xH^T \neq \mathbf yH^T$.  With this as background, I believe
that the OP is asking

> For a given $N$ and $\epsilon = \frac{D}{N} \in (0,1)$, what is
>   the largest $K$ such that a $[N,K,D]$ linear code over $\mathbb F_2$
>   exists, and how do I go about finding the paritycheck matrix $H$
>   of such a code?

People studying coding theory have looked at this problem
extensively in the past but a complete solution is not known,
except for some small values of $N$.  See, for example,
[this tabulation](http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~math/Logiciels/Magma/text1571.htm)
for some results.

Comment: Thank you -- I'll look into that. To be precise, I did not dismiss your comment as off-track; but did not see *how* to cast my problem to meet in the standard code theory settings.